# mapStateToProps can not find reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React/Redux world but from my understanding a reducer gets added to the global state of the app. When i reference it in my mapStateToProps though i get a `ReferenceError: books is not defined`

books_reducer.js

```
export default function () {
  return [
    { title: 'Book1' },
    { title: 'Book2' },
    { title: 'Book3'}
  ]
}
```

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import booksReducer from './books_reducer'

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  books: booksReducer
})

export default appReducer
```

container.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return(
      this.props.books.maps((book) => {
        return(
          <li key={book.title} className='lsit-group-item'>{book.title}</li>
        )
      })
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ul className='list-group col-sm-4'>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return(
    books: state.books
  )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

import App from './containers/containers'
import appReducer from './reducers/reducers'

let store = createStore(appReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(store.getState())` before you do the render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might have a syntax error in your `mapStateToProps` function.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return(
    books: state.books
  )
}
```

You probably meant to return an object literal.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    books: state.books
  };
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have already created the store. Don't know why i didn't include that. Updated question